# Conditional include tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I've ran into very strange behavior of Django template system. I have a template file, namely `test.html`, which recursively includes itself:

```
{% include "test.html" %}
```

Of course, such template has no chance to be rendered, since there is no finishing condition. OK, let's try the following:

```
{% if test_false %}{% include "test.html" %}{% endif %},
```

where `test_false` is a variable passed to template and equal to `False`.

One expects that it just will not include anything, but it does:

```
RuntimeError at /test/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I don't get it. Include tag can take arguments from current context, so I doubt it is executed before any other part of the page. Then why does it ignore condition tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django has optimization that include templates that are given by constants at compilation.

Set name of template to variable and include it in that way:

```
{% include test_template %}
```

Django will not be able to use it's optimization and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Like Thomasz says, Django can only make this optimization if the path is defined as a constant string in the including template - like so:

```
{% include "test.html" %}
```

But I would rather not have to put the template path in the context from Python code.

So here is a slightly more self contained way of achieving the same result - wrap the include in a `with`:

```
{% with "test.html" as path %}
    {% include path %}
{% endwith %}
```