# Django - how to convert a nested directory/file tree dict to html?

Tags: django, python-3.x

how do i create nested html structure annotated with clas='file' / class='folder' from the following?

```
{
  'dir': {'subDir':[['file', size], ['file2', size],]}, # contents not a dict 

 'dir2': {'subDir':{'subDir': ['file', size],
                          0 : ['file', size]}}, # 0 not a directory
     0 : ['file', size]
}
```

equivalent to

```
dir
   subDir
         file
         file2
dir2
   subDir
         subDir
                file
         file
file
```

i would appreciate a full example based on my snippet

the structure of my dict is the most compact way can i think of to store directory structure into a db blob, but its too much for the template to unpack because it's not uniform

```
a single level structure would look like this
    [['file', size],
     ['file2', size2],
     ]
```

so doing a simple 'for k,v in items' within the template would not fly

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tags are **not** recursive (you must be explicit with the maximum number of levels you will represent, by nesting that amount of tags) you have to create your own tag or processing function which supports recursion (only in python code - django templates can never be recursive by themselves).

Have you tried rendering a template conditionally inside a template? that could be a workaround.

See the [Include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include), it's the only way to perform a kind of recursion (including the same template in the current template) - otherwise you must create your own -recursive- tag.

Comment: you can easily create inclusion tags and assignment tags, and i think that even block tags. django provides helpers which are detailed in the page I gave - actually I never figured it until yesterday (I never felt the need for a custom tag)

Comment: "including the same template in the current template" (even conditionally) will cause **RuntimeError** (maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object)

Comment: By this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950275/conditional-include-tag-in-django such optimization would not occur anymore