# Strategy for handling recursive template display in Django

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-templates

I'm rewriting a family tree app in Django that I previously wrote in Laravel. There's an 'outline view' page where I start with the 'original families' at the top of the tree, and show an outline of their children, their children's families/kids, those kids' families/kids, etc.

First I've generated a big nested list with all the info (in the controller for laravel, and in views.py in my Django rewrite). Then I give that list to a couple of views to display the lists for each original family. (Code included below)

Testing the logic a couple levels at a time it works, but when I let it call recursively and load my outline page, it gives me a recursion error: `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.`

Reading around, it sounds like python has a known limitation that it doesn't handle tail recursion, and I saw some posts saying that showing recursive views isn't good practice in Django.

Update: I've also started down the road of making a management command to generate an html page for this (that I can just show statically, and regenerate when I add new people), and that way I do avoid the recursion error.  I'll do a bit more debugging with the original views to see what I can find out about where/when I reach the error (only for one particular branch or family, etc?) in case there's something I can fix in the way I generate the list.

Is there a better way to approach this problem in Django?

outline_whole.html:

```
    {% for entry in results %}
        {% get_class entry as object_type %}
        {% include chunk_view %}
    {% endfor %}
```

outline_family_chunk.html: (aka chunk_view, passed into the context)

```
{% get_class entry as object_type %}
<ul>
{% if object_type == 'Family' %}
    <a href="{% url 'family_detail' entry.id %}">{{ entry.display_name }}</a>
{% elif object_type == 'Person' %}
    <li>{% include "familytree/person_name_link.html" with person=entry %}</li>
{% elif object_type == 'list' %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in entry %}
            {% include chunk_view with entry=item %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Example of the list it's working through- it gives a family with its children, then a list for the next family (where one of the original children was a parent):

```
[<Family: The Skywalker family (Anakin & Padme)>, <Person: Luke Skywalker>, <Person: Leia Skywalker>,[<Family: The Solo family >, <Person: Kylo Ren>]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional include tag in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950275/conditional-include-tag-in-django)

Comment: Thanks Abdul! I may not be understanding that linked post: it sounds like it'll work if I add a variable name for the view, but so far I'm still getting the same error. I've updated my code above with the addition- is this the right understanding?

Comment: Does passing the template name into the context from the view work?

Comment: Okay now I'm passing the variable 'chunk_view' from the original page context (and updated my code above)- the template is successfully found, but when I let it call the recursion I still get that error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. It seems like this error is unrelated (or at least un-helped-by) using a variable name for that view, unless I'm misunderstanding what you meant?

Comment: Can you show the template `person_name_link`? Does it also recursively include some templates? Also what is `entry` exactly?

Comment: I think you're reinventing the wheel, when there's no need for it. There's several packages dealing with trees. From [data model](https://pypi.org/project/django-treebeard/) to [menus](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-treenode).

Comment: thanks Abdul!  person_name_link has nothing interesting (just gives a link to that person's person detail page). The recursion error is only there when I include the block of code starting with {% elif object_type == 'list' %}. The 'entry' will be a chunk of data made up of a Family object and Person objects for any kids that family had. I've added an example into the description above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: thanks Melvyn- I'll have a look at those!

Comment: This [grid](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/navigation/) has a view tree menus and [this one](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/) deals with models. Django packages is a good site to get an overview of the eco system.

Comment: If you push your work in progress to your github repo, I'll be happy to take a look. I don't quite understand why you'd get into a recursion error, unless you have 1k levels deep tree or one of the trees goes into a loop, because of a backreference to a parent.

Comment: Okay thanks!!  Here’s the repo: https://github.com/dianekaplan/familytree-django/tree/master/mysite/familytree/
1) templates/familytree has the code discussed above (outline_family_chunk.html called from outline_whole.html, called from outline.html). 
2) management/commands has my other approach: I made “makeBranchOutlineHTML.py” to generate static html files instead, but that management command hit a similar recursion error.

Comment: I see the data model doesn't prevent infinite recursion, but it's hard to see where loops could occur without data. Is there a publically downloadable .ged file I can import that causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So without data it's hard to see where the problem is, but the obvious candidate is:

```
this_user -> Branch -> descendants[] --\
  ^                                    |  <- has this_user
  |______<___________<__________<______/
```

So when rendering a person, you render his branch, for which you call get_descendants and then from what I can tell, this could include the top-level user and we go round and round.

But like I said, it's a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your hypothesis. Rendering the outline doesn't actually involve rendering the user. In views.py, the outline context includes this_user only for a header link. The outline view itself begins with branches, doing one loop to show a list of the oldest families, and one loop through branch/original family/show descendants. (Currently I have a workaround: a management command makes the html for each branch and I show that directly). Sorry for the guesswork. I hesitate to make my family tree live, but I'll try to reproduce with a sample gedcom file this weekend. thanks for looking!

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked for a sample one :D There's a limit to what one should put online :) And it's a good exercise to see if you can come up with a sample one. If not, then I'm afraid the corruption is local.